# Vite не создаёт совместимость с IE 10

Tags: vue.js, vite, ie11

Пишу SPA приложение Vue3 + Laeavel + Vuex, для сборки фронта используется Vite. Появилась необходимость в совместимости с IE 10. Но никак не получается настроить всё так, чтобы оно в нём работало.
Перепробовал 100500 методов и Babel и build: { target: browserslistToEsbuild() } последнее что испробовал legacyPlugin() для Vite. Все браузеры показывают, IE 10 упирается.

```
//app.js
import './bootstrap';
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import router from "./router.js";
import vuex from "./vuex.js";
import 'core-js/stable';
import 'regenerator-runtime/runtime';

import GuestLayout from "./layouts/GuestLayout.vue";
import UserLayout from "./layouts/UserLayout.vue";

const app= createApp({});

app.use(router);
app.use(vuex);

app.component('guest-layout', GuestLayout);
app.component('user-layout', UserLayout);

app.mount('#app'); 

//vite.config.js[![введите сюда описание изображения][1]][1]
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';
import legacyPlugin from '@vitejs/plugin-legacy';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/sass/app.scss',
                'resources/js/app.js',
            ],
            refresh: true,
        }),
        vue({
            template: {
                transformAssetUrls: {
                    base: null,
                    includeAbsolute: false,
                },
            },
        }),
        legacyPlugin({
            targets: ['IE 10'],
            ignoreBrowserslistConfig: false,
            corejs: true,
        }),
    ],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            vue: 'vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js',
        },
    },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Итак, как оказалось, подружить IE10 и Vue 3 оказалось недостижимой задачей. В итоге поставил Webpack + Babel и Vue 2. Сейчас всё отлично работает.

Comment: через ие 10 ещё к вам заходят?

Comment: Сочувствую конечно, IE это сплошные проблемы, наверное лучше даже использовать Vue 1, так как некоторая функциональность все равно может работать непредсказуемо в Vue 2